# grep for string in all files in directories with certain names

Tags: bash, directory, grep, find

I have csv files in directories with this structure:

```
20090120/
20090121/
20090122/
etc...
```

I want to grep for a certain string in all of the csv files in these directories, but only for January 2009, e.g. 200901*/*.csv

Is there a bash command line argument that can do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. `grep "a certain string" 200901*/*.csv`.

Answer (score 5):

You need something like:

```
grep NEEDLE 200901*/*.csv
```

(assuming your search string is `NEEDLE` of course - just change it to whatever you're *actually* looking for).

The `bash` shell is quite capable of expanding multi-level paths and file names.

That is, of course, only limited to the CSV files one directory down. If you want to search entire subtrees, you'll have to use the slightly mode complicated (and adaptable) `find` command.

Though, assuming you can set a limit on the depth, you could get away with something like (for three levels):

```
grep NEEDLE 200901*/*.csv 200901*/*/*.csv 200901*/*/*/*.csv
```

Comment: Or, you could [set globstar and use **](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#globstar)

Answer (score 4):

**Try this :**

```
grep -lr "Pattern" 200901*/*.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a combination of **find** to search for specific filename patterns and **grep** for finding the pattern:

```
find . -name "*.csv" -print -exec grep -n "NEEDLE" {} \; | grep -B1 "NEEDLE"
```